# Change a desktop icon (not shortcut) in code

Tags: c#, windows, icons, desktop, explorer

I want to be able to change the image of a desktop icon [not a shortcut] to reflect events that have changed in a windows service. This needs to be done dynamically during normal run time - so the icon will need to be changed and the windows explorer notified of the change and refreshed.

I have tried EZNamespaceExtensions.net but this will not work under windows 7 security.  Any sugestions?

Comment: Is the icon for an application or some type of data or content file?

Comment: It's for a windows service (C#). Basically the service notices something has happened and wants to change the desktopicon to draw the users attention to it. The service is running under a local system account so it has sufficient rights to change values in the registry where the icons are held - but changing the icon doesn't change the desktop.

Comment: Tell us more about the desktop icon. Is it a file with a custom extension? Is it a namespace extension? (Note that the behavior you describe is highly unusual. It is not how icons are meant to be used. For example, the icon for a file should depend only on the file, not on the state of some service.)

Comment: The aim is to use the icon to indicate the state of a process similar to a mail process.  Furthermore it will act as the target of a drag and drop - and be clickable to open a window.  We don't really care how this behaviour is achieved - but it is part of a spec we don't control.  We had hoped to use namespace extensions and the Ezenamespaceextensions product mentioned above does do this - but not when windows 7 security prevents changing the icon in the registry when running as an ordinary user.  Since we have a service running under a local system account this seemed an obvious try.